# About using the Quad-copter motors as power generator (charging its battery when do nothing)

Tags: generator, quad-copter

I am searching the Lego based quadcopter projects via [google search](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=AOaemvIgV26uqAxkFhb4uzQZYfohbd0ojw:1634609041878&q=lift+more+weight+by+connecting+drone+together&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQj6aasdXzAhUNgtgFHSRBDO0QBSgAegQIARA0&biw=1848&bih=948&dpr=1) it this project, [like show below](https://newatlas.com/drones/multiple-drones-heavy-loads/):

[image]

So some quadcopter combining toughener to do bigger works, for example by combining some  number of different drones [like said here](https://hobbyhenry.com/how-much-weight-can-a-drone-carry/), like  20 number of 60g drone with Lego base connection the lifting power could be multiplied around 15 time stronger which could be 15*140g=2,100g base of the [below calculation](https://www.omnicalculator.com/other/drone-motor) :

[image]

So as these drones would be on high distance with powerful wind, we can charge their battery by fixing their situation as their paddles start rounded with the wind, of this purpose I have tried to see it is possible to use the typical drone motors ([brushed and brushless motors.](https://dronenodes.com/drone-motors-brushless-guide/))  which is said **Both brushed and brushless DC motors can be operated as generators.** In [here](https://www.newequipment.com/plant-operations/article/22061031/dc-motors-as-generators).

So if possible I like to have some comment about using the quadcopters motors for charging their batteries, especially for the below list:

about the correctness of charging the quadcopter power by their motors and the wind

about the external hardware required for doing this action (if possible, Arduino base or Arduino plugin gadget)

**Update 1:**

For charging the drone could be settled automatically on high building like [small wind turbine used on some high building](https://www.google.com/search?q=high%20bulding%20%20as%20small%20wind%20turbine&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi79diXqdbzAhXItKQKHbX_D70Q2-cCegQIABAA&oq=high%20bulding%20%20as%20small%20wind%20turbine&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1DaD1iEIWDPImgAcAB4AIAB4QWIAakdkgELMi03LjEuMS4xLjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=YKVuYbvFKMjpkgW1_7_oCw&bih=948&biw=1833&hl=fa#imgrc=oFVrSBk9PSXuBM) like shown below with replacing the wind turban with settled drones:

[image]

**Update 2:**

Based on the [DamienD](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/81885/damiend) answer, I added this Update. So I have one post in medium site about the **[In relation to Quadcopters, garbage collection ...](https://elasa2next.medium.com/in-relation-to-quadcopters-garbage-collection-and-artificial-intelligence-in-progress-f15b3e1f8a93?source=user_profile---------0----------------------------)**, in this post I have written about some balloon-quadcopter which could be used for transferring the multiple quadcopters to near target for having synchronous drone job like described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwUHlbsf9wE) or at below ([paper link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/330591649_Design_and_Implementation_of_Cloud-Like_Soft_Drone_S-Cloud)):

[image]

But in this scenario I am trying to have some charging procedure like by using the drones motors or the host motors (bigger and more efficient), for  doing more on-air request.
If possible it would be great to have some more calculation about the efficiency of creating the charging power for different drone motors (like [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=quadcopter%20motors%20comparison%20best%20%5D&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CXcC-wLfrp4VYUoXqnL9M8UUsgIGCgIIABAA&bih=945&biw=1680&hl=fa&sa=X&ved=0CCEQuIIBahcKEwiojt_j3dbzAhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQBw#imgrc=GCszkwG3k0S4SM&imgdii=J1CFWjL3FDKFzM), [2](https://droneomega.com/drone-motor-essentials/), [3](https://www.google.com/search?q=quadcopter%20motors%20comparison&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CeF8BCA5Mx4HYQKKilBObC3MsgIGCgIIABAA&bih=945&biw=1680&hl=fa&sa=X&ved=0CBwQuIIBahcKEwigvbrK3dbzAhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQEQ)), also this could be easier by using the small wind turbines charts as can see below (like [1](https://short.gy/VSAlgE),[2](https://www.google.com/search?q=small%20wind%20turbine%20power%20and%20wind%20speed&sxsrf=AOaemvLtIgTbtUjpDaqYGXALX71OvF--cQ:1634653795048&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO8aL219bzAhXY5nMBHWuoARoQ_AUoAXoECAMQAw#imgrc=W2R243gmFYBBIM),[3](https://www.google.com/search?q=small%20wind%20turbine%20power%20and%20wind%20speed&sxsrf=AOaemvLtIgTbtUjpDaqYGXALX71OvF--cQ:1634653795048&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjO8aL219bzAhXY5nMBHWuoARoQ_AUoAXoECAMQAw#imgrc=Q0KOOevE3-X4WM)):

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: "So as these drones would be on high distance with powerful wind"_ - What 'high distance'? What 'powerful wind'?

Comment: @Bruce_Abbott, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are suggesting charging the batteries of some of the quadcopter set while flying, that won't work.  The motors being used as generators would create drag and additional load for the ones keeping the group aloft, wasting more power than was generated.

If you want to use the blades to charge the batteries when the copters are stationary, you have a few large problems in that you have to keep the axis parallel to the wind and the motors were not designed to be used as generators, so assuming they could generate at all or with even passable efficiency, the operational speed and output voltage at which they would achieve an acceptable output is not likely to be coincidentally the same as the speed as a random wind would push them at.  This may necessitate changes in bearings, gearing or frame, and would require a complicated MPPT charge controller, which could be built into your other requirement, a charge circuit for the lithium ion batteries compatible with the output voltage of the generator.  Just keep in mind any time you convert energy, like from chemical to electrical, electrical to mechanical in the case of a quadcopter, you have necessary losses.  Some energy is converted, and some is lost to entropy in heat, unrelated vibration, non useful movement, etc.  So using made up, exaggerated numbers:  when you charge a battery, only 70% of the power you put in is stored.  When you run a motor from the battery, only 80% of what was stored comes out as electricity and another 0.5% is wasted heating the wires to the motor.  The motor converts 70% of that energy to rotational force(disregarding large losses when starting or changing speeds) and the propeller shape converts 80% of that to useful thrust at reasonable operating speeds.  Charging a battery involves the same thing backwards, so if you're working one set of motors against the others, the power going into the battery plus losses appears as thrust against the other motors, which must draw that amount of power from the battery plus losses.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible to use a propeller on an aircraft to generate power.  Google's Makani spent 13 years studying this problem, including building actual large scale aircraft, flying them and generating power from wind.

Although the company eventually folded, they released much of their work into the public domain, including a detailed report discussing the engineering challenges of generating wind energy from a platform that is also an aircraft:

https://storage.googleapis.com/x-prod.appspot.com/files/Makani_TheEnergyKiteReport_Part1.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Before you start, take a brushed DC motor and spin the motor - it spins easily.  Now connect the two motor wires together and spin the motor again. Not so easy. That is similar to the motor charging a dead battery. It takes physical power to move the electrons to fill the battery.
Note: charging the battery will be like some low value resistor 5 to 50 ohms. A resistor between the wires will allow the motor to turn a bit easier but, still significant force is required. Spinning to Charge a battery is much different than spinning a disconnected motor.

Answer (score 1):

My intuition is that although technically possible, this would be so inefficient with small propellers, that it would not really be worth doing except in very specific scenarios. For instance if complete autonomy is very important and it's ok if the drone spends 99% of the time charging and 1% flying. But that's only my intuition, someone should do the maths ;)

Some projects are doing something similar using a drone or kite on a tether. In that case it's the tether spool that contains the generator and produces energy as wind or thermals carry the UAV upwards.

Comment: I have updated the question, if you like, take a look on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe a different approach would answer the question; what if an algorithm was involved to reduce some or all motors speed and their power consumption during the presence of aiding winds, with the use of the appropriate data received from all gyroscopic and acceleration sensors then returning the speed to the required level without affecting the performance or velocity etc.
these micro savings on the run would start to be meaningful with time and can be considered as savings in term of power, considering that calculation consumed energy are minor compared to the spared energy.

Answer (score 0):

> For charging the drone could be settled automatically on high building
> like small wind turbine used on some high building like shown below

Yes, that could work.

> about the correctness of charging the quadcopter power by their motors
> and the wind

The battery is connected to the motor through the ESC (Electronic Speed Controller). When the motor is spun by wind going through the propeller it generates a voltage proportional to rpm. If the ESC uses [synchronous rectification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_rectification) then it may be possible to modify the firmware so it performs [regenerative braking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regenerative_brake) to recharge the battery even when the generated voltage would not normally be high enough to exceed the battery voltage. The flight controller would monitor battery voltage and current, and adjust the amount of regeneration to suit the charging requirements (must not exceed full charge voltage or maximum rated charging current).

> about the external hardware required for doing this action (if
> possible, Arduino base or Arduino plugin gadget)

If the drone already has the required features then no extra electronic hardware may be required, just modified firmware in the ESCs and flight controller (which could be Arduino based). The challenge will be to find a way to fix the drone in place so wind blows through the propellers.

> If possible it would be great to have some more calculation about the
> efficiency of creating the charging power for different drone
> motors... also this could be easier by using the small wind turbines
> charts

Calculations based on just the motors or on data from wind turbines will have poor accuracy. I suggest doing your own tests with the actual motors and propellers that will be used in the drone. It might be easier to get the charging system working first and then collect battery charging data from it, as this takes into account all the losses and is ultimately what you are interested in.

Expect efficiency to be poor. But this doesn't matter so long as the drone can recharge sufficiently to meet mission objectives. For example it might spend all night charging and only collect enough energy to work for 10 minutes during the day, but this might be acceptable since it can work unattended and the energy is free.